# Dynamic pipes in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In angular 2 I had created a dynamic filter of sorts.  What it let you do is to keep a filter spec in a database, then use it like this:

```
{{ someItem.value | dynamic : someItem.filterSpec }}
```

What really made it work was $interpolate.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this in angular 2.  I made something work, but I can't really find any infrastructure like $filter to be able to find, for example, that when the person says

```
number:'0.1'
```

that he means DecimalPipe.  The source for DecimalPipe shows the annotation but I don't see any public infrastructure to let me find it.

Is there a way?

For now I have a rough workaround, but even that has an issue.  My dynamic pipe does:

```
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
```

That's fine but I would really like to be able to then Inject it into my pipe, but there's no provider for DecimalPipe that I have been able to find.  So for now I just create one with 'new' but I feel like that's the wrong long-term thing to do.

Q1: is there a public API for finding pipe instances by name?

Q2: Is there some provider I can declare that will allow me to inject pipes?

Answer (score 0):

A1: I believe is https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=pipe what you are looking for

A2: Injecting pipe into a `component` is done through `pipes` field:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  pipes: [MyCustomPipe],
  ...
})
```